# drag and drop directive with jqueryUI angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem doing this with angular:

http://jsfiddle.net/EpxHE/14/light/

This is what I made:

Directive:

```
.directive("myDirective", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            replace: true,
            compile: function (element, attrs) {
                var $newDiv = $("<div class='dragdiv'>4</div>");
                makeElementAsDragAndDrop($newDiv);
                element.html($newDiv);
            }
        }

    })

function makeElementAsDragAndDrop(elem) {
    $(elem).draggable({
        snap: '#droppable',
        snapMode: 'outer',
        revert: "invalid",
        cursor: "move",
        helper: "clone"
    });
    $(elem).droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var $dragElem = $(ui.draggable).clone().replaceAll(this);
            $(this).replaceAll(ui.draggable);
            makeElementAsDragAndDrop(this);
            makeElementAsDragAndDrop($dragElem);
        }
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div my-directive ng-repeat="item in items"></div>
```

I think the problem is because the makeElementAsDragAndDrop() function is call only once and before the element is created. Do you have a solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did something very similar to what you're trying to do. However, instead of in my directive's compile function, I instead attach the jquery ui widget to the directive element inside my link function, like so:

```
app.directive('sortable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elt, attrs) {
      return elt.sortable({
        revert: true,
        stop: function(evt, ui) {
          return scope.$apply(function() {
            /* code goes here */
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Notice that immediately after defining the `stop` event on my sortable widget, I call `scope.$apply`. Misko Hevery has described that as getting back into the `Angular execution context`.

I found out how to do this from [Ben Farrell's blog post](http://www.benfarrell.com/2013/03/30/drag-and-drop-with-angularjs-and-jquery-ui/).

You can also see how I did it, posted here in my [GithHub repo](https://github.com/KurtRMueller/SmartDeck).

Comment: Remember `$scope.apply`!!! Omitting this simple call blocked my progress for a couple of days.

Comment: Excellent - thanks! In case it helps others, I was having a hard time getting this to work until I realised that the `ng-repeat` affects the scope: [from the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat), it instantiates a template _with a new scope_ once per item. So any changes you make to `scope` in the `link` function will only be visible inside the `ng-repeat`.